# Android application's cache

Tags: android, caching, webview, httpclient

What data is stored in application's cache directory? I'm not using it in my application and I still can see its size grows. Is it webview caching images? HttpClient storing some data? What else?

Can I erase it's contents safely from code at any time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android [can clean the cache up whenever it's running low on space](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), so the assumption for whatever application using cache files should be that they can be deleted at any time. In other words, if you're using some other modules that create the cache in your application, you should be able to delete those files safely at any time, assuming those modules are well coded. What it will do to performance, that depends on many more things.

Maybe just keep the size under control, so delete the older files when you feel it gets too big? I think Android recommends 1MB for cache.